# How to collaborate on a flash project?

Tags: flash, collaboration

I'm making a project in flash together with 4 more people, but we've faced the problem of having to recheck two files to see what's the newest version of them (because sometimes a member of the team has to have access to all of the files), also, we're not together every time...

This is our first project and I have not much of an idea of what to do. I suppose we need a server to ensure access to the same files, as well as a check-in/check-out system.

Also, I've seen some "project collaboration tools" like manymoon, but it just creates assignments without the file hosting.

We don't have any money, but I have a free web host, in case it is needed (although I prefer a free website).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subversion (SVN) is an open-source revision control system that seems to fit the bill for what you need.  There are some free online options that offer online subversion hosting.  The two that I have heard of / used are [SourceForge.net](http://www.SourceForge.net) and [Assembla.com](http://offers.assembla.com/free-subversion-hosting/).  SourceForge is only for open source projects so your code and assets will be visible to the outside world.  Assembla has both open and closed source options.  The closed source option will limit you to 1Gb of storage for the free version which is generally enough for flash projects (but that depends on the project).

In the teams I've worked with, we didn't use any exclusive file locking (where checking out a file restricts the access to that file for other users) and instead opted to merge the files back together when there are conflicts.

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) is a great free open-source client for Subversion that generally merges files by itself seamlessly when you submit your modifications.  In a 5 person team the need for manually merging files should be very low.

There are of course many other options but these are the ones I have used to great success with small teams.

Comment: I use Subversion, and it is probably the best tool out there, but be careful because the merge function does not work at all with fla, swc or swf files.  This often causes problems, so a check in/out system is better when you can't check the file's availability.

Comment: Thank you!!! Just one question... is there a tutorial on using assembla with tortoiseSVN? I hope it's easy to learn n.n"

Comment: Hmm not sure if there is a tutorial but assembla will help you create a new project (it's very simple, you just have to supply a name and establish read / write rights for people working on the project) then you should find a URL that looks something like https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/NameOfMyProject which is the repository URL.  Once you have that URL and you have installed TortoiseSVN, create a new folder where you want to store your project, right-click on the folder, choose "SVN checkout" and set the URL of repository as the one found earlier.

Answer (score 1):

we have faced the problem many time. First i also recommend a good version control system as Godfather said. You can use Subversion of Git (we've switched to git and it's way faster and cleaner to me). Using a version control you can compare your work with the work of your team and merge them.

Unfortunately Flash .fla files are lare binary files (this changed in the latest version exactly for this reason) and if you use an old version of Flash every changes is saved in the same large binary file with assets. I recommend to put your AS3 code into separate .as files in the directory to reduce the conflicts of working on the same file at the same time and share assets (png, jpeg, mp3 ...) outside the .fla.

You can find many services that offer version control hosting (Assembla, sourceforge, google code, github ...) and for small team the fees are not to high. If your team is localized on the same network you can setup your own server quite easily

Hope this helps